# Azure secret download issue on linux using az keyvault

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu-18.04, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, trying to use Azure CLI (2.0.56) to download Secret from Azure KeyVault. The download of the Secret works fine in Powershell on Windows but on Linux it fails with the following error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The command itself:

```
az keyvault secret download -n secret-file --vault-name testkeyvault -f /usr/src/secret-file.json
```

I have tried to save the file with UNIX Line Endings, the encoding is UTF-8, I can open the file with `cat` in Linux, I can even set secret using the same file and `az keyvault secret set` in Linux but can't download it straight after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help someone searching a similar issue. I believe the issue is with the implementation in `Azure CLI`. As a workaround I have used [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the content of secret myself after using the `show` instead of `download` operation.

Here is the command to do that:

```
az keyvault secret show -n secret-file --vault-name testkeyvault | jq '.value | fromjson' > /usr/src/secret-file.json
```